# php mysql atomic ' Select and Delete ' on a Table

Tags: php, mysql

I have an script of a queue like situation which each user can post a request which is added to the queue and others can accept these requests by the order of that queue but each request should only be accepted by one user .
but if I implement it with two queries one for the select other for the delete

something Like this

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id,CreationDate FROM `RandomQueue` order by CreationDate limit 1 ;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    echo "this request is accepted".$row['id'];

    $sqlDel = "DELETE FROM `RandomQueue` WHERE id = {$row['id']}";
    $conn->query($sql);
}
?>
```

it would not work because many problems may occur like two user accepting one request and so on..(mutex problem) is it possible to achieve this by one sql query(to make it atomic)? and if not then any suggestion on how to implementing this logic would be nice ,thanks a lot;

Comment: If your table is of type InnoDB and you are using PDO you are looking for [PDO beginTransaction](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php) and [PDO commit](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atomicity is one of the database transaction properties (ACID), so you need make sure your database engine support transaction.

In MySQL, MyISAM doesn't support transaction and you must use InnoDB.

If you are using InnoDB, there are two ways to start database transaction for MySQL in PHP

```
/* Begin a transaction, turning off autocommit */
$dbh->beginTransaction();

// your business logic goes here

$dbh->commit();
```

or

```
$mysqli->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_ONLY);
// your business logic goes here
$mysqli->commit();
```

Comment: Thanks jacob and Dave for your Suggestion ,but as I understood this approach makes it atomic as if one of the two queries fail it would undo every thing done but my problem is not just that

Comment: it is possible that at the same time one user get the select result (before deleting it) another user might get the same result because its still not deleted and there will be two users getting the same row which I want to prevent

Comment: @AmirRasti within a transaction, you prevent two users from selecting the same row using `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.  ("update" is still used, even if your intention is "delete").

Comment: Great then, thanks. I vote up useful comments and marked the answer